# how to convert Date(2019/5/10) to shamsiDate(1398/4/12)

Tags: web-services, date, jpa, swagger, spring-framework-beans

I had called a web service in my code that contains Deadline Date . the problem is the response in swagger shows like this :

```
{
    "id": "289",
    "serviceName": "خدمت 1",
    "deadLine": "2024/05/06",
   ...
...
  }
```

and I want to show deadline in Shamsi Date like 1398/4/12.
i have used a lot of convertors but it did not worked for me  and still shows the  `"deadLine": "2024/05/06",`

this is my view  :

```
public String setDeadLine(Date deadLine) {
        this.deadLine = deadLine;
         String dateFa;
       //String  dateFa= DateConvertor.miladi2date(deadLine);

       dateFa=  this.ConvertToPersianToShow(deadLine);
       return dateFa;
    }


    public String ConvertToPersianToShow(Date  deadLine)
    {
        CalendarTool cl = new CalendarTool();
        String date;
        String year = cl.getIranianYearInCentury();
        String Month = cl.getIranianMonthStr();
        String day = cl.getIranianWeekDayStr();

        date = year+"/" + Month + "/" + day;
        return date;
    }
```

should I type any code in my controller ?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVE : 
I just need to add some code in ConvertToPersianToShow :
calendarTool should be filled .mine was empty 
I added this code :

```
 String[] date = deadLine.split("/");
        if(date.length != 3)
            return null;
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(date[0]),Integer.parseInt(date[1]),Integer.parseInt(date[2]));
```

and filled the calendar :

```
 CalendarTool cl = new CalendarTool(calendar);
```